# Non-latin characters in smarty template showing ���� while using getDateLocal

Tags: php, encoding, smarty

How can I fix this bug? I am using smarty template. Here is code:

```
writeTR2($lngstr['page_visitordetails_startdate'], getDateLocal($lngstr['language']['date_format_full'], $i_rSet1->fields["startdate"]));
```

The result is ���� 05, 2013 04:16:39
Should be like this Март 05, 2013 04:16:39

My database and website are using UTF-8, in other places I do not have this issue everything showing good. I mean Cyrillic characters are showing good. But when I use this function getDateLocal there is a problem. When I change the Encoding to Cyrillic(ISO-8859-5)
that function shows me character but whole sites showing incorrect.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

� is always indicative of non-UTF-8 characters being displayed in a UTF-8 environment. You'd have to either change `getDateLocal()`'s output to UTF-8, or convert on the fly:

```
$dateLocalConverted = iconv("ISO-8859-5", "UTF-8", getDateLocal($lngstr['language']['date_format_full'], $i_rSet1->fields["startdate"]));
```

that's a dirty fix, though - it would be best to find out why `getDateLocal()` is outputting ISO-8859-5 data, and fix that.

Comment: I am using multilanguage in my system, english version is using ISO-8859-1. If I convert everything will be converted, Am I right?

Comment: @Firdavs I don't know what you mean by "multilanguage"? Anyway, the `iconv()` call will convert only the getDateLocal() contents. You are definitely using UTF-8 on the output side

Answer (score 0):

try using the following php function:

```
convert_cyr_string ( string $str , string $from , string $to )
```

Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-cyr-string.php for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `getDateLocale` in particular, but if it uses the system's locale system, you need to set the locale in an appropriate encoding:

```
setlocale('en_US.UTF8');
```

Consult your system what locales you have available and in what encoding.

Comment: setlocale('ru_RU.UTF8') is already done, but I have problem only with particular smarty function getDateLocale. In other places setlocale is working fine.

Comment: I cannot find any official reference to that function. What does it do?

Comment: Here is link http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format it returns full date in smarty template